# Does temporary tables effect schema size in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, temp-tables

I running a MySql DB at a webhosting company. The size limit of a schema/DB is set to 100M. I'm using temporary tables in my query like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_foo
SELECT * FROM Foo INNER JOIN Bar ON Foo.bar_id = Bar._id
```

Will that effect the size of a schema in a way that is detectable or does the result of temporary tables got saved somewhere else?

Comment: This question migth also fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ , I guess...

Comment: This will help you in your quest for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560860/are-tables-created-with-create-temporary-table-in-memory-or-on-disk AS discussed, it depends on the engine you specify